# Google Analytics Source / Medium issue

Tags: php, google-analytics

I use this https://github.com/ins0/google-measurement-php-client library to track the invoices and I can't make Source / Medium to get working. It shows me that everything is from (direct) / (none) when I log in Google which it shouldn't.

My code is something like this in order to parse cookie data:

```
$params = explode('|', $aCookie['__utmz']);
$parts  = explode('.', $params[0], 5);

array_unshift($params, $parts[4]);

$paramMap = array(
             'utmcsr'   => 'setCampaignSource',
             'utmgclid' => 'setAdwordsID',
             'utmdclid' => 'setDisplayAdsID',
             'utmccn'   => 'setCampaignName',
             'utmcmd'   => 'setCampaignMedium',
             'utmcct'   => 'setCampaignContent'
            );

foreach ($params as $param) {
  list($key, $val) = explode('=', $param);

  if (isset($paramMap[$key]) === TRUE) {
    $oObject->{$paramMap[$key]}($val);
  }
}

$sAdwordsID = $oObject->getAdwordsID();

if (empty($sAdwordsID) === FALSE) {
  $oObject->setCampaignName('google');
  $oObject->setCampaignSource('google');
  $oObject->setCampaignMedium('cpc');
}
```

I set Campaign Source and Medium manually if AdwordsID is set. On query post I get no errors, transaction item is showing up in Google Analytics however Campaign Source and Medium is still (direct) / (none).

Comment: There is not utmz cookie in universal analytics, so you won't have much luck getting any values from there.

Comment: I do get the data from utmz cookie since I dump the object and see everything is set correctly, I mean campaign source and medium that are google / cpc. The problem is that Google Analytics shows me only (direct) / (none) which is nonsense.

Comment: Universal Analytics uses a single cookie _ga (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains?hl=de) unless you have an UA enabled account that still uses the old tracking code; since this will be phased out you should not invest too much energy in a solution that soon will fail.